# loading a css style sheet through firebug console

Tags: javascript, css, firebug

Is there a way to load a style sheet through the firebug console? I know that the console is javascript but is there and extension that allows fire bug to load stylesheets?

Comment: You could append a `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="whatever.css" />` to the `<head>` by using the console (by using `document.createElement` and setting the properties, `document.getElementsByTagName("head")`, and `.appendChild`)

Answer (score 3):

You can add a stylesheet via html-editor in firebug